# How to define a new left-aligned environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

I am working on preparing a document in latex, and I need to define an new environment as follow:

When the code is:

```
\begin{IF}
    the sum of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 10,\\
    the product of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 14,\\
    the sum of squares of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 54;
\end{IF}
```

It is displayed like this:

```
IF: the sum of a, b and c is 10, 
    the product of a, b, and c is 14;
    the sum of squares of a, b, and c is 54;
```

Note that:

1. the first sentence of the body is preceded by the keyword "IF", i.e., they are in the same line.
2. these three sentences in the body are left-aligned.

Can you help me define this IF-environment? Thankssssssss!!

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option using a list with the help of [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth\mylen{IF:~}}

\newlist{MIF}{description}{1}
\setlist[MIF,1]{leftmargin=*,labelsep=0pt,itemindent=-\mylen}
\newenvironment{IF}
  {\begin{MIF}\item[\textnormal{IF:~}]}
  {\end{MIF}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{IF}
  the sum of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 10,\\
  the product of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 14,\\
  the sum of squares of $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 54;
\end{IF}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength}{\mylen}{IF:~}}`